# If $|AB|=a$ and $|CD|=c$ what is the sum of $\overrightarrow{BA}+\overrightarrow{DC}=?$

Tags: vectors

If $|AB|=a$ and $|CD|=c$ what is the sum of $\overrightarrow{BA}+\overrightarrow{DC}=?$

Lets  have a trapezoid ABCD with bases AB and CD. 
 $|AB|=a$ 
 $|CD|=c$ 
 $a\geq c$

Calculate the length of vectors:

1. $\overrightarrow{BA}+\overrightarrow{DC}=$ strictly theoretical this would be $= -\overrightarrow{AB}+(-\overrightarrow{CD})= -\overrightarrow{a}+(-\overrightarrow{c})=-\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{c}$ 
    In the solutions there is written: $\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{c}$

Where the heck did I made a mistake?

The same happened when calculating $\overrightarrow{AB}-\overrightarrow{DC}=\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{c} \implies $the official solution is $\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{c}$ 
 and $\overrightarrow{BC}-\overrightarrow{AD}=-\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{c} \implies $the official solution is $\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{c}$

I also drew a picture and drew all the vectors. But the official solutions aren't making any sense. Are they wrong? Or did I made a colossal  mistake somewhere?

Comment: Try writing out entirely what the exercise says. Your title alone does not have an answer, and alot of what you write does not make sense.

Comment: In the trapezoid ABCD with parallel sides AB and CD, the vectors $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{DC}$ have opposite orientation.

Comment: @RichardJensen  Is there something mathematically wrong? Can you please point out what does not make sense to you? Or you don't like the way I wrote the problem? If you point out the specifics I would be happy to edit my post :)

Comment: @user376343 If you look at the point 1. you will see I included opposite orientation. The question here: Did I calculated everything OK and are official solutions wrong .... or did I miss something and made an error?

Comment: @thunder Things like when you write $\overrightarrow{BA} + \overrightarrow{DC} =  -\overrightarrow{a} - \overrightarrow{c}$. $a$ and $c$ are scalars, while the others are vectors, so equality doesn't make sense.

Just to make sure. You are asked to find the vector $\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{CD}$ and its length?

Comment: @RichardJensen Got It! I should really be more careful about this! Will edit it!